# Exception thrown from fallback not getting caught- Resilience4j

Tags: spring-boot, resilience4j

I am trying to implement Resilience4j by replacing Hystrix as my circuit breaker.
The happy path is working absolutely fine but in case of an exception, the code is reaching the fallback method but when I rethrow the exception from fallback, it is never getting caught.
Is there something I am missing ?

```
public CompletableFuture<String> fallBackMethod(Throwable e) {
        String exceptionMessage = "";
        if (e != null) {
            exceptionMessage = e.getMessage();
            LOG.error(" Inside Fallback. Could not reach remote service {}", exceptionMessage);
        }
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
```

I am expecting it to be caught the service which is invoking the circuit breaker but everytime it skips the catch block.

Can I rethrow an exception from fallback or it is not even possible ?

Thanks

Comment: @RobertWinkler, i am having the same issue. Can you help please? The [documentation](https://resilience4j.readme.io/docs/getting-started-3#fallback-methods) does not touch on this use-case and reading the [code](https://github.com/resilience4j/resilience4j/blob/master/resilience4j-spring/src/main/java/io/github/resilience4j/circuitbreaker/configure/CircuitBreakerAspect.java) does not help me as i don't know AOP. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a feature, because throwing an exception from another exception, is not a fallback.

What i ended up doing is, the fallback will return me the state of the circuit breaker, like so:

```
private final CircuitBreakerRegistry circuitBreakerRegistry;
io.github.resilience4j.circuitbreaker.CircuitBreaker circuitBreaker = circuitBreakerRegistry.circuitBreaker("cbName");
return circuitBreaker.getState().name(); //most of the time will be CLOSED, OPEN or HALF_OPEN
```

and based on the returned value, i will throw an exception accordingly.